# HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost changed in Delphi 10.3, lost parameter Data

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a component that uses `HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost` that previously used the `data` parameter, but in version 10.3 of Delphi this parameter was replaced.

Before Delphi 10.3:

```
procedure TNotaBlu.BeforePostHTTPRequest(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Client: THTTPClient);
var
  Certificado:  ICertificate2;
  CertContext:  ICertContext;
  PCertContext: Pointer;
begin
try
    Certificado := VCertificadoDigital.GetCertificate.DefaultInterface;
    CertContext := Certificado as ICertContext;
    CertContext.Get_CertContext(Integer(PCertContext));

    if  (not InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, PCertContext, 100)) then
```

In this code, I use `internetsetoption`, how should I proceed now in Delphi 10.3? How to get the `data` parameter?

Comment: Have you tried using `nil` as a replacement for `data`?

Comment: The problem is that from 10.3 the RIO request handling has been replaced by a completely different request framework. So the the data parameter might be something else then the handle to an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnNeedClientCertificate event to set the certificate like this:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1NeedClientCertificate(const Sender: TObject; const ARequest: TURLRequest;
  const ACertificateList: TCertificateList; var AnIndex: Integer);
begin
  for var i := 0 to ACertificateList.Count -1 do
  begin
    if ACertificateList[i].CertName.Contains('Test') then
    begin
      AnIndex := i;
    end;
  end;
end;

enter code here
```