# HTTPReqResp OnBeforePost change in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, wininet, delphi-10.3-rio, internetsetoption

I have an event code that previously used the `Data` parameter, but in Delphi 10.3 this parameter was replaced.

Before Delphi 10.3:

```pascal
procedure THTTPEvents.HTTPReqResp1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
begin
  // set the certificate to use for the SSL connection
  if not InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, PCertContext, Sizeof(CERTCONTEXT)*5)
    then Raise Exception.Create('Problema no certificado!');
end;
```

In this code, I use `InternetSetOption()`, how should I proceed now in Delphi 10.3? How to get the `Data` parameter?

```
procedure THTTPEvents.HTTPReqResp1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
  Store        : IStore;
  Cert         : ICertificate2;
  CertContext  : ICertContext;
  PCertContext : PCCERT_CONTEXT;
begin
  try
    if not FileExists(HTTPEvents.PFXFile) then
      Raise Exception.Create('Ficheiro de certificado não encontrado!');

    HttpReqResp.ConnectTimeout := 12000;
    HttpReqResp.ReceiveTimeout := 12000;
    HttpReqResp.SendTimeout := 12000;

    // create Certificate store object
    Store := CoStore.Create;
    Cert := CoCertificate.Create;
    Cert.Load(HTTPEvents.PFXFile, HTTPEvents.PFXPass, CAPICOM_KEY_STORAGE_DEFAULT, CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_KEY);
    CertContext := Cert as ICertContext;
    CertContext.Get_CertContext(Integer(PCertContext));

    // set the certificate to use for the SSL connection
    if not InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, PCertContext, Sizeof(CERTCONTEXT)*5)
      then Raise Exception.Create('Problema no certificado!');
    CertContext.FreeContext(Integer(PCertContext));
  except
    ON E:Exception DO ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

All the code in BeforePost Event. This piece of code not work in delphi 10.3, because the parameter "Data". This problem drive me crazy, if someone help i appreciate.

Comment: Similar question: [HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost changed in Delphi 10.3, lost parameter Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56737356/576719)

Comment: @LURD That question doesn't have an answer either!

Comment: @nolaspeaker, yes, but linking similar questions together makes it easier to find a solution, once one of them is solved.

Comment: Look here: [How to set client certificate under Delphi 10.3.2 using InternetSetOptionA](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/data-internet-and-web-services/f/internet-clients/69932/how-to-set-client-certificate-under-delphi-10-3-2-using-internetsetoptiona)

Comment: A link to documentation: [Handling Client-side Certificates](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_an_HTTP_Client#Handling_Client-side_Certificates)

Comment: Can't find the way to replace the code with the information from the various links sent. If possible, I still need your help.